# Site recommendation for hardware problem

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem with my brother DCP-1510 printer and need to ask to some wise folks of stackexchange about it. In particular, it was supposed to be a multipurpose printer(allowing scanning as well) but now there were issues with the driver installation. I was able to search for the driver using the device manager, but the scanning function is not functional. Please, recommend me the site in which I can ask this question.