# Stack Exchange site for PC hardware questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask "What went wrong with my stick of RAM and its interaction with the MB", but I can't find a relevant SE site?

Similar questions:

[Site recommendation for hardware problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288010/site-recommendation-for-hardware-problem). This is about "hardware" as in a printer, talking about drivers. Not appropriate.

[Stack Overflow for hardware / embedded systems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39135/stack-overflow-for-hardware-embedded-systems). Is, unsurprisingly, very much more about embedded systems than MB components.

A good answer there, cites these Exchanges:

- Stackoverflow - Programming.
- ServerFault - Seems to be much more sys-admin-y and about integration and networking etc. Inter-computer hardware, not components.
- SuperUser - Similar to ServerFault but more more software/OS focussed?
- Chiphacker - Electrical Engineering, soldering, chip programming. All way to low level for what I want.

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ This appears to be talking at the correct level ("What GFX card should I buy?" etc) but appears to be specifically for asking for purchase recommendations, not discussions of problems.

---

- **Is there another Stack Exchange site I can go to?**
- **Have I mis-judged any of the sites above?**
- **Is this just not something that SE covers at the moment?**

Comment: When you say "what went wrong" do you mean they're incompatible or did one or the other fail at some point? The former might be OK on SU but the latter is just about impossible to answer without detailed schematics and design information which is why those questions don't go well on EE.

Comment: I mean "I had <this> sequence of behaviour, which I found surprising. Is this normal for a bad stick of memory, or does it indicate that something else is wrong (say with the MB slot), or is it genuinely just a bit a weird".

Comment: But if "Is this incompatable" might be suitable for SU, then it sounds like it should be a sensible place for my question.

Comment: This question has a short breakdown on a few of these sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299162/where-to-ask-iptables-related-questions/299179#299179

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for the question as it seems to involve behavior of PC memory at a fairly high level. While most questions probably relate to software and operating systems they're not adverse to hardware related questions and for example the [hardware-failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-failure) tag there has 1339 questions.

I'm a regular user at Electrical Engineering and quite a few higher level PC hardware questions get migrated there and seem to get good answers. Out of the other options you've listed Stack Overflow would be a definite no-go, and Server Fault only a possibility if it related specifically to RAM in a server environment.